# windows phone 7 observablecollection in listitem

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have an `ObservableCollection<testItem>` and every `testItem` has another `ObvervableCollection<testData>`.

Know for every `testData` I want a `ListItem` with some Data of the `testItem` and from `testData`. At the moment I set the `ObservableCollection<testItem>` as `ItemsSource` of the List but than I get only the first item of the `itemsData`.

What can I do?

UPDATE:

xaml:

```
<ListBox Name="ResultList" ItemsSource="{Binding TankstellenItem}" >
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
     <Border BorderBrush="#FF3AACDF" BorderThickness="4">
       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                   Background="White" 
                   UseLayoutRounding="True" Tap="ItemIsClicked">
        <StackPanel Width="130" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <Border BorderThickness="2" 
                    Background="#FF3AACDF" BorderBrush="White">
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding PriceBigDigits}" 
                              FontFamily="Assets/Font.ttf#LCD" 
                              FontSize="25" TextAlignment="Center" />
            </Border>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding FuelType}" 
                       TextAlignment="Center" 
                       FontSize="15" Foreground="Black"/>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding UpdateDate}" 
                      TextAlignment="Center" 
                      FontSize="15" Foreground="Black" />
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding DistanceString}" 
                      TextAlignment="Center" 
                      FontSize="15" Foreground="Black"/>
       </StackPanel>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="400">
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" 
                    FontSize="30" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black"/>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}" FontSize="20" Foreground="Black" />
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding PLZCity}" FontSize="20" Foreground="Black" />
       </StackPanel>
  </StackPanel>
   </Border>
   </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

than I have the testItem:

```
public testItem{
DistanceString (string),
Title (string),
Addresse (string),
PLZCity (string),
itemDates (ObservableCollection<itemData>)}
```

And the itemData:

```
public itemData{
PriceBigDigits (string),
FuelType (string),
UpdateDate (string)
```

Comment: Can you add a little more detail. Instead of the text, perhaps you can include some sample code showing what you are doing?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you may want to bind the `itemDates` to a `ItemsControl`'s `ItemsSource` property. So wrap your second `StackPanel` within the `DataTemplate` of an `ItemsControl`.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Can you give me an more detailed example?